# Uniformly Random Tuples

Tags: probability, algorithms, random, multisets

Consider a multiset of natural numbers. As an example take

$$ M = \{1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3\} $$

If we treat copies of the same number as indistinguishable, there are 8 distinct 2-tuples we can form from this, by not using any number more often than it appears in $M$:

$$ \{ (1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (3,1), (2,3), (3,2), (2,2), (3,3) \} $$

Is there an algorithm which generates one of these tuples with uniform probability, without having to generate all the tuples up front and selecting one at random? Note that the uniformity is in reference to the list of tuples, so $(3,3)$ should appear with the same probability as $(2,2)$ or $(1,2)$, respectively.

The algorithm should work for arbitrary non-empty $M$ and $n \leq |M|$, where the goal is to generate $n$-tuples.

Ideally, I'm looking for an algorithm that is not based on rejection, but if that is not possible, I'd also be interested in how I can minimise the number of necessary rejections to generate the tuples efficiently.

If special cases (i.e. small, fixed $n$) yield good algorithms, I'd still be interested in those, even if they don't generalise to larger $n$.

Comment: If you have $M = \{1,2,2,3,3,3\}$, does it mean than $(3,3)$ should appear more often than $(2,2)$ or not?

Comment: No, as the $3$s are indistinguishable, there is only one copy of $(3,3)$ in the pool to draw from (just as there is one copy of $(2,2)$), so they should have the same probability.

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski You pick uniformly from (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,1), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) if I understand correctly.

Comment: Then if $n$ is not too high (not much higher than the most rare items in $M$), then you may just to generate a random tuple from $M'$ (every item of a tuple is taken randomly from $M'$ with the same probability for all items from $M'$), where $M'$ is a set of distinct items from $M$. If some items appear in tuple more times than in $M$, generate the tuple again. Of course, in case when $M$ is like $\{1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4\}$ and $n=6$ you will have to do too many re-generations but in other cases it works well (I used similar uniform random algorith in my bachelor's thesis).

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski Ah yes, that would probably work. I'll add a note about rejection-based algorithms.

Comment: Considering your answer to the first comment, Wouldn't be superfluous to have element counts (in the multiset) greater than $n$ (tuple size)? In your example, wouldn't $\{1,2,2,3,3\}$ be exactly equivalent?

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, any algorithm could remove those first, but since it didn't make a difference, I figured it would simplify the problem statement to use general multisets (instead of multisets which don't contain more than $n$ copies of any number).

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant of [leonbloy's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1143987/184069) with the same basic idea: compute the number of tuples that begin with a given element, and use those numbers are weights in a random choice. If $n$ is small compared to $|M|$, this method is asymptotically much faster. However, it is **not** any faster than simply generating all possible tuples and choosing uniformly from them.

Let $C_i$ be the number of distinct elements that have multiplicity $i$ in $M$, and denote $c_i = |C_i|$. We may assume that $c_i = 0$ for $i > n$. Denote by $N^n_i(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)$ the number of distinct $n$-tuples drawn from $M$ whose first entry is an element of $C_i$ (this number only depends on $n$, $i$, and the $c_j$). Then we have the recursion formula

$$
N^n_i(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0, & \mbox{if } c_i = 0 \\
1, & \mbox{if } n = 0 \\
c_i \sum_{j=1}^n N^{n-1}_j (d_1, \ldots, d_n) & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.
$$

where $d_{i-1} = c_{i-1} + 1$ (if $i>1$), $d_i = c_i - 1$, and $d_j = c_j$ for all other $j$. The first two cases are self-explanatory, and the final case holds because we choose one element of $C_i$, which gives the multiplier $c_i$, and for the second slot of the tuple, we choose an element from one of the $j$ updated multiplicity classes, where $C_i$ has lost one element and $C_{i-1}$ gained one.

After the computation, you use $c_i^{-1} N^n_i(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)$ as the weight for the elements of $C_i$, randomly choose an element of $M$, and repeat for the next slot.

As @leonbloy suggests, the tuples should be cached for performance. The number of tuples to keep in memory, and the time complexity of the algorithm, is at most $\sum_{\ell = 1}^n (\max \{ c_i : i = 1, \ldots, n \})^\ell$, which is $O(|M|^n)$ if $n$ is fixed. In @leonbloy's algorithm, this number seems to be of the order $n^k$ where $k$ is the number of distinct elements in $M$. If $n$ is close to $|M|$ and/or $k$ is small compared to $|M|$, @leonbloy's solution is probably faster. Note that $n \leq |M|$ holds in all nontrivial cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here, i think, is one way:

1. Construct the probability generating function for ordered $n$-tuples of $M'$ (the set of distinct elements of $M$ mentioned by @AndreiRykhalski) with replacement (i.e., without constraints on the number of appearances of any element). The coefficients are the $n^\text{th}$ list of $|M|$-nomial coefficients, but the terms themselves are needed for the next step.
2. Remove any impossible terms, i.e. with variables raised to powers larger than their counts in $M$. Concession: This might be prohibitively awkward. Depending on implementation, it might be done within step 1, so that you don't end up calculating huge generating functions. (Sorry, this involves rejection.)
3. Sample from the remaining terms, weighted by their coefficients.
4. Sample uniformly from the multiset permutations encoded by the selected term.

In your example, $M$ contains 3 distinct elements, so the generating function for ordered tuples of these elements has trinomial coefficients (step 1): $$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+2xy+2xz+y^2+2yz+z^2$$ The term $x^2$ corresponds to the impossible pair $(1,1)$, so delete it (step 2). The remaining pairs have total weight 8, so sample an integer between 1 and 8 (step 3). I get 8, so i pick the term $z^2$, which corresponds to $(3,3)$. Had i instead gotten 3, i would pick the term $2xz$ and have to choose between $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$ (step 4).

I'm not a seasoned programmer, so i can't speak to the scalability of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let the elements of the $k-$sized alphabet be indexed by $i=0,1 \cdots k-1$. Let $n$ be the tuple length, and let the vector ${\bf a}=(a_0,a_1,\cdots , a_{k-1})$ ($a_i\ge 0$) denote the available number of elements.

In the example: $n=2$, $k=3$, ${\bf a}=(1,2,3)$.

Let $N({\bf a},n)$ count the total number of tuples subject to the restriction.

Then an algorithm could be: for each $t=0 \cdots n-1$, for each $i=0 \cdots k-1$ compute
$w_i = N({\bf a}^{[i]},n-t-1)$ where ${\bf a}^{[i]}$ is equal to ${\bf a}$ except for the $i-$th  element, which is decreased by one. Then compute a random integer   $s$ in  $[0 \cdots k-1]$ with probabilities proportional to the weights $w_i$, assign this to the tuple $X_t:=s$ and update ${\bf a}:= {\bf a}^{[s]}$

To compute $N({\bf a},n)$ we can use the recursion:

$$N({\bf a},n)=\sum_{i=0 }^{k-1 }N({\bf a}^{[i]},n-1)  $$

with $N({\bf a},0)=1$, and $N({\bf a},n)=0$ if ${\bf a}_i <0$ for some $i$.

If we care about performance, and if we plan to generate many tuples, we should precompute or cache the results of the above.

Sample Java code (non optimized) at [Ideone](https://ideone.com/SfiWKu)

Comment: Shouldn't the index $t$ in your recursion formula go to $k-1$ instead of $n-1$? Also, what is the meaning of the index $t = 0 \cdots n-1$ in the preceding paragraph?

Comment: I made some fixes. $t$ indexes the tuple position, $i$ indexes the elements of the alphabet (letters) from which we select the index  $s$

Comment: But why does $w_i$ depend on $t$?

Comment: @IlkkaTörmä The weights depends on the counting of the tuples; and this must be done, not for the original tuple size ($n$) each time, but for the "current" (remaining) tuple size $n'=n-t-1$